# Python getline() issue

Tags: python, file, getline

I am trying get data from file and store them in vector, but I found some difficulties. 
Thats how my Python script look like:

```
from numpy import array, append
from linecache import getline
print 'read file'
t = []
f = open('file.dat', 'r')
b = getline('f',4).split()
t.append(int(b[0]))
```

After run I get information:

```
t.append(int(b[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I am checking b appears to be empty:

```
>>b
[]
```

On the 4th line in file.dat I have digit 4, it is only one entry in this line.
There is anyone how know what is wrong? I am using 2.7 Python version.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your error is that you are miss using [`linecache.getline`](http://docs.python.org//library/linecache.html?highlight=getline) you should do:

```
from numpy import array, append
from linecache import getline
print 'read file'
t = []
b = getline('file.data',4).split()
t.append(int(b[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter for `getline` is the filename.

```
b = getline('file.data',4).split()
```